# facetQuery Rest API throwing 400 error when using nested attributes

Tags: algolia

I'm getting a 400 when trying to search for a nested attribute facet field

e.g. a post request to the following url will give me

```
http://xxx-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/index_name/facets/work_experience.company/query

{"message":"Cannot search in `work_experience.company` attribute, you need to add `searchable(work_experience.company)` to attributeForFaceting.","status":400}
```

However a non nested attribute facet search works

```
http://xxx-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/index_name/facets/language_names/query
```

I've double checked and the facets are correctly added to attributes for faceting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "json facet" ? Are you speaking about a nested attribute?

Comment: Sorry bad terminlogy I made up :). so
`{"language_names": ['english', 'spanish'], "work_experience": [{"company": "algolia"}]}`

`language_names` would be a non nested facet field,
and `work_experience.company` would be the nested facet field.

Comment: Just tested it, works on my side. Do you confirm you added `searchable(work_experience.company)` to your `attributesForFaceting` index setting?

Comment: Yes, I've checked the algolia.com display settings page, and my local settings, and they are both added. I can see all the facets + counts on the algolia dashboard too.

Comment: Okay It works if I wrap `searchable()` around the nested attribute. I must say that is confusing and inconsistent with the rest of the non nested facets. Any reason it must be wrapped in a `searchable()`?